# Unable to perform Spectral Angle Mapper (SAM) for target detection on hyperspectral data in python

Tags: python, spectral-python

I am working on hyperspectral satellite imagery and I am trying to implement SAM algorithm on my dataset.I am trying to use spectral_angle and msam functions which are available in spectral python library.
I am using following commands. Dataset after preprocessing has dimensions (2000,2000,20)

> > signature=image_cube[300,500,:]
> > mmn=spectral_angles(image_cube,signature.reshape(1,20))

I am getting an numpy array containing all values 'Nan'.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently have NaN values in your data. Assuming `image_cube`, try this:

```
image_cube[np.isnan(image_cube)] = 0
signature=image_cube[300,500,:]
mmn=spectral_angles(image_cube,signature.reshape(1,20))
```

Depending on the data type of `image_cube`, you may have to convert it to a floating point type first. Also, you can replace the zero with whatever floating point value you like (e.g., the mean spectrum).